# Заменить буквы в слове JS

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять почему не работает `replace`, задача с freecodecamp(дана фраза, в словах которой, буквы из первой половины алфавита нужно заменить на буквы второй половины алфавита соответственно т.е А=N, B=O и т.д), все решения связанные с этой задачей были через `charCodeAt()`,можно ли вообще решить эту задачу через `replace`?

```
function rot13(str) { 
   const alfabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
   const half1 = alfabet.split('');
   // ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"]
   const half2 = half1.splice(0,13);
//    ["N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
   const myStr = str.split(' ');
   for(let myShifrWords of myStr){
       for(let i=0; i<myShifrWords.length;i++){
           let e = myShifrWords[i];
           function repl(e){
             if(half1.indexOf(e)!==-1){
                 return half1[half2.indexOf(e)];
                } else if(half2.indexOf(e)!==-1){
                 return half2[half1.indexOf(e)]
                }
            }
return myShifrWords.replace(e, repl);
       }
   }
}
rot13("SERR CVMMN!")
```

Comment: FREE PIZZA!@entithat

Comment: да, именно так @entithat

Comment: Проблема тут: `return myShifrWords.replace(e, repl);` посреди цикла

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  var map = Object.create(null);

  for (var q = 0; q < alphabet.length; ++q) {
    map[alphabet[q]] = alphabet[(q + 13) % alphabet.length];
  }

  return str.replace(/./g, m => map[m] || m);
}

console.log(rot13("SERR CVMMN!"));
```

Answer (score 2):

А можно ещё и так.

```js
function replace(str) {
  return str.replace(/[A-Z]/gi, function(letter) {
    var c = letter.charCodeAt(0);
    return String.fromCharCode((c - 65 >= 13) ? c - 13 : c + 13);
  });
}

console.log(replace("SERR CVMMN!"));
```

Короткое описание: берём букву из нужного слова, смотрим в какой она части алфавита (в первой или второй), если первая - по коду ASCII таблицы прибавляем 13 (кол-во букв в половине алфавита) и получаем "параллельную" букву, и наоборот, если буква из второй части алфавита.

Comment: код работает, но вопрос именно через `replace` сделать и можно ли это сделать  @entithat

Comment: `A-z` - неверно

Comment: Ещё раз: `A-z` в регулярке - неверно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z, понял)) Но в любом случаи сработает только с капсом.

Comment: Ага, теперь верно :)